# Auto generating id(WEB API2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have  WebAPI2 project.

I controller I have POST method

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(StartWorkingDay))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostStartWorkingDay(StartWorkingDay startWorkingDay)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.StartWorkingDays.Add(startWorkingDay);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (StartWorkingDayExists(startWorkingDay.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = startWorkingDay.Id }, startWorkingDay);
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
 public partial class StartWorkingDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string INN { get; set; }
}
```

At this point I need to add Id when send post request.

When I send first request it creates data in table with `id:0`

Next request is empty response and no data in table.

How I can make id generates automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate id on the database side. It is easy to do with [`DatabaseGenerated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute. Generating id value on inserting row is achieved this way:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Or with fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StartWorkingDay>().Property(d => d.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

After you will modify the configuration, make sure that changes are propagated to the database. That will happen automatically if you are using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` or `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` database initializer.

Comment: Added it, but it still not works if I not send `id` field

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene do you use code first migrations? Or what kind of database initializer you are using? Make sure that identity specification exists at the database Id column `IDENTITY (1, 1)`

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene that's all relates to Entity Framework. Your database should be updated with new entity configuration